# TLS 1.2 - unable to run .NET 5 WebApi clean template (Windows 7 + VS 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl, tls1.2, iis-express

I've been struggling with it the second day. I created a .NET 5.0 WebApi template in Visual Studio 2019 (simplest WhetherForecast). When I run the solution, the browser opens and I get the message (Firefox browser):

[image: SecureConnectionFailed]

The machine I tried to run it on has Windows 7 (SP1) installed, and based on what I read, it should still support .NET 5. However I think the problem is with some internet configuration itself, because when I go to `about:config` in Firefox, and change the setting `security.tls.version.min` from `3` (TLS 1.2) to `1` (TLS 1.0) then it opens fine. I already tried:

- removing local certificates and repairing IIS Express 10
- following the guide to enable TLS 1.2 on Win7: https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3008/how-do-i-enable-tls-1-2-on-windows-7.html

but without any luck.

I could of course switch to TLS 1.0, and Win7 setup is just temporary, but I'm curious what's the cause of this error. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is actually running on .NET 5? Are you sure you have changed all the correct registry settings? Are you sure you installed [the relevant updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)? I strongly recommend you move to a version of Windows which still has support for security updates, W7 went end-of-life 2 years ago

Comment: Instead of using third party websites with strange recommendations I would use the documentation provided by Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392